# Converting PDF to PNG with same resolution - Imagemagick

Tags: file, format, imagemagick, ocr

I have 1000s of PDFs with multiple pages and each PDF has different resolution (based on scanners used to scan them). I want to convert each page of PDF to PNG to pass it to Tesseract for OCR. I used Imagemagick to convert to PNG but have to pass a fixed DPI for all images to get a good readable output. Is there a way I can convert each PDF by preserving the resolution of that PDF too?

For example, if 1.PDF has resolution 622 × 788 and 2.pdf has resolution 792 × 612, I want the exact conversion with same resoultion just a different format(PNG).

The command I am using right now is:

```
convert -monochrome -density 1200 input.pdf -resize 25% -monochrome -white-threshold 50% -black-threshold -50% output.png
```

Thanks,
pashah

Comment: please add the command you are using to convert as well. only that way it is possible to obtain an answer that actually explains something

Comment: sorry..have updated the post with command

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps read the geometry of the first page, then resize all pages to match?

```
SIZE=$(identify -format '%g' input.pdf)
convert  -monochrome \
         -density 1200 \
         -resize $SIZE \
         -white-threshold 50% \
         -black-threshold -50% \
         -append \
         output.png
```

Comment: Thanks @emcconville. However, this does not preserve the resolution. The output png image is degraded.